# Geting UNIX Timestamp while logging history

Tags: linux, unix, time, timestamp

I am running below bash script which is saving the history in a file, however it is logging the history with Unix epoch timestamp. I need the timestamp in human readable format.

```
_who_am_i=$(who am i|awk '{print $1}')
_ID=$(id -u $_who_am_i)
if [ "$_ID" > 0 ]
then
export HISTSIZE=10000
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
export HISTFILE=/var/log/users_historylogs/history-users-$(who am i | awk '{print $1}';exit)-$(date +%F)
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the [Fine Manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-history), the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable applies to the output of the `history` command.
The history file always contains Unix timestamps.
This is necessary so that the `bash` itself can parse it.